# Sails lift error 'Cannot find module 'express/node_modules/cookie'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to create my first sails app and I've followed the steps on the sails getting started (http://sailsjs.org/get-started). But when i try to do a sails lift, i get the following error:

```
(node:11291) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported.     If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent   version.
module.js:442
    throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'express/node_modules/cookie'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/master/Desktop/Developer/NodeJS/HelloSails/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/session/index.js:9:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at /Users/master/Desktop/Developer/NodeJS/HelloSails/node_modules/sails/lib/app/configuration/index.js:54:28
at Function.reduce (/Users/master/Desktop/Developer/NodeJS/HelloSails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3735:25)
at Configuration.defaultConfig (/Users/master/Desktop/Developer/NodeJS/HelloSails/node_modules/sails/lib/app/configuration/index.js:53:18)
at Configuration.bound [as defaults] (/Users/master/Desktop/Developer/NodeJS/HelloSails/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
```

I tried manually removing the 'node_modules' folder, inserting express as a dependency in my package.json and running 'npm install', but that did not work.

Im running  Node v6.2.2 Sail v0.10.5 and NPM v3.10.6

What am i missing here?

Comment: hi.  did you ever get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

update sails version to latest, it is issue of npm structure, old version use tree level dependency while new version use same level structure
[sails upgrade version](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/upgrading)

Answer (score -2):

It's a dependency issue with npm, this worked for me when I had the issue.

`npm -g install npm@latest`